# Surely it's not Sny again

Tags: word, no-computers

Each dot is a light, which shines in exactly one direction, horizontally, vertically, or diagonally (like a bishop, in a 45-degree angle). Lights shine through each other. Uncover the secret message from the unlit cells. The solution is unique, that is, only one of the 35 trillion combinations produce the desired secret message.

[image]

This is one of the possible configurations, which doesn't produce a secret message:

[image]

Comment: You have a very funny definition of "unique"...

Comment: ^ As in, there are no two configurations that produce the same desired result. What is so funny?

Comment: I counted ~453 trillion combinations...

Comment: How? I just did 15^8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I signed on just as this was posted. I put it in MS Paint and stared at it for a few minutes, and after playing around with it for a bit, I got this:

> [image]

Comment: Correct! R3C3 was intended to go top right instead of top left, though, since it resembles a P more closely.

Comment: @SnySmartie  Good point. edited now